# Cleanup Policy:Compact/Delete and log.retention

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a question about Kafka Topic cleanup policies and their interaction of log.retention....

For example, if I set cleanup.policy to compact, compaction will only start after the retention time of the topic or retention time has no effect for compaction?

Second part of the question, if I use compact,delete together, and I have log.retention for lets say 1 day, topic compacted all the time but content of the topic will be deleted after one day? or compaction and delete realised after one day?

Thx for answers...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Log segments can be deleted or compacted, or both, to manage their size. The topic-level configuration `cleanup.policy` determines the way the log segments for the topic are managed.

**Log cleanup by compaction**

If the topic-level configuration `cleanup.policy` is set to `compact`,the log for the topic is compacted periodically in the background by the log cleaner.

In a compacted topic,the log only needs to contain the most recent message for each key while earlier messages can be discarded.

There is no need to set log.retention to -1 or any other value. Your topics will be compacted and old messages never deleted (as per compaction rules).

Note that only the inactive file segment can be compacted; active segment will never be compacted.

**Log cleanup by using both**

You can specify both `delete` and `compact` values for the `cleanup.policy` configuration at the same time. In this case, the log is compacted, but the cleanup process also follows the `retention time` or `size limit` settings.

I would suggest you to go through the following links

https://ibm.github.io/event-streams/installing/capacity-planning/

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist

Comment: For info, the default `cleanup.policy` is currently `delete`. Source = https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#cleanup-policy